# Rails Ckeditor S3 uploaded image url expire after awhile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ckeditor, carrierwave

I'm developing a posting feature where user can create new post using CKEditor in Rails. The image uploaded to S3 using carrierwave.

I noticed an issue that the image url store in database is something like this `"https://somebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/freight/ckeditor/pictures/11/content_logos1_0000_Singapore-Logistics-Association.jpg?X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Date=20180626T094950Z&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIJ2MY37H6GCRA66Q/20180626/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=072ca2de6c07d8388c1ac338b110c05fba39329b9a8155689bfe040c555993e1"`

This URL will be expired. And after a minute, the post will not display the image anymore.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

UPDATE: Found a solution for this:

- Make S3 folder public
- Add this code to S3 Image Uploader class to make it generate public url instead of presigned one.

  class CkeditorPictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    configure do |c|
      c.fog_public = true # or false
    end
  end

Comment: Dynamically generate signed S3 url while displaying the image on front end. You cant use the url stored in DB. There is also option in when posting image to S3. The url in policy details you can provide large expiration time.

Comment: @SatishakumarAwati My problem is this whole url is store as a part of raw field in database which including other content like html tags etc. so I cannot think about a way to dynamically generated signed link.
One solution I'm thinking about right now is make this specific folder public, and save the url without expire params

Answer (score 1):

You should set expiry time in picture uploader

```
class CkeditorPictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
          # rest of your code
          # public all images

          def fog_public
            true
          end


 end
```

Answer (score 0):

The url is expiring after a minute, because this is a **presigned-url** which is meant for expiration after a particular interval of time ,  they are used to access private files in a s3 bucket for a short duration of time.

If you want to access the url for longer, you can extend the time while generating url through  your code , or If use case wants your object to be publicly accessible to all , then you can make your object public instead and then use it's s3 hosted url to point to that object.

```
import boto3
s3Client = boto3.client('s3')
s3Client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params = {'Bucket': 'www.mybucket.com', 'Key': 'hello.txt'}, ExpiresIn = 100)
```

This is an example in python that generates a presigned url that expires in 100 seconds